# Ajax returned title value for tooltip isn't in one line, in Bootstrap

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am having a weird bug with dynamic created tooltips using ajax. I am creating a simple **notes function**. When data is coming from the database everything looks nice
[image]

But when i am creating a new note, using ajax i am creating the new entry in the db and then return the value to be shown in the new tooltip...But this is how it comes out to the user.
[image]

Is there a way to 'force' it to one line like the 1st image  ?
Here is the code in question:

.js part

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    placement : 'left'
});
////////
var inText = $('.evnt-input').val(); //Whatever the user typed

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'request.php',
    data: {action:'addnotes', data: inText},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(s){
        if(s.status == 'success'){
       $('<li id="'+s.id+'">' + inText + '<a href="#" class="event-close" data-toggle="tooltip" title="'+s.curTime+'"> &#10005; </a> </li>').appendTo('.event-list');
     }
    },
    error: function(e)
    {
        console.log('error');
    }
});
```

.php part

```
if ($_POST["action"] == "addnotes"){
    function addnotes($data)
    {
        $insert = db_query("insert into notes(description) values('$data')");
        if($insert)
        return db_inserted_id();
    }

    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $status = addnotes($data);
    if($status != ''){
        $timestamp = strtotime(date('Y-m-d G:i:s'));
        $curTime = date( 'F j, Y, g:i a', $timestamp ); 
        $output = array('status'=>'success','id'=>$status, 'curTime'=>$curTime);
    }   
    else
        $output = array('status'=>'error');

    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

I have an identical code with the .js part to show the notes when the page loads...of course that works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Lol it was so easy.... I changed the .js part to this, to 'reinitialize' the tooptip:

```
if(s.status == 'success'){
   var curTime = s.curTime;
   $('<li id="'+s.id+'">' + inText + '<a href="#" class="event-close" data-toggle="tooltip" title="'+curTime+'"> &#10005; </a> </li>').appendTo('.event-list');
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
        placement : 'left'
    });
 }
```

Comment: what do you mean ?